# unable to resolve/implement onMapReadyCallBack interface

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, android-mapview

I have updated the Google Repository but it didn't help and i have added the dependency which has resulted in the build error ... 
I am stuck .. I need to implement this interface because I want to use the getMapAsync() method and use mapview...

Please assist me in this .. I have searched for similar errors and usually installing he Repository or adding the dependency helped ..but when I added the dependency I got this error

Error:(47, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-service:+
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

[image]

Comment: post you build.gradle

Comment: `com.google.android.gms:play-service` is incorrect, it should be `com.google.android.gms:play-services`

Comment: Thank you so much .. this error got fixed .. however, it still does not recognize OnMapReadyCallback interface .. it is still in red and it asks me if I would like to implement the interface!

Comment: I just rechecked the dependencies but could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services added .. when I tried to add it again .. it says Library play services is not installed do you want to install repository .. i keep answering yes and nothing happens ...

Comment: ok i just added the dependency  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0' and it got added successfully .. now my error is fixed and i was able to import :)

Answer (score 1):

the dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0' should be added to the project